# add colorbar to a sequence of line plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I have a sequence of line plots for two variables (x,y) for a number of different values of a variable z. I would normally add the line plots with legends like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax  = fig.add_subplot(111)
# suppose mydata is a list of tuples containing (xs, ys, z) 
# where xs and ys are lists of x's and y's and z is a number. 
legns = []
for(xs,ys,z) in mydata:
   pl = ax.plot(xs,ys,color = (z,0,0))
   legns.append("z = %f"%(z))
ax.legends(legns) 
plt.show()
```

But I have too many graphs and the legends will cover the graph. I'd rather have a colorbar indicating the value of z corresponding to the color. I can't find anything like that in the galery and all my attempts do deal with the colorbar failed. Apparently I must create a collection of plots before trying to add a colorbar.

Is there an easy way to do this? Thanks.

EDIT (clarification):

I wanted to do something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm     as cm

fig = plt.figure()
ax  = fig.add_subplot(111)
mycmap = cm.hot
# suppose mydata is a list of tuples containing (xs, ys, z) 
# where xs and ys are lists of x's and y's and z is a number between 0 and 1
plots = []
for(xs,ys,z) in mydata:
   pl = ax.plot(xs,ys,color = mycmap(z))
   plots.append(pl)
fig.colorbar(plots)
plt.show()
```

But this won't work according to the Matplotlib reference because a list of plots is not a "mappable", whatever this means.

I've created an alternative plot function using `LineCollection`:

```
def myplot(ax,xs,ys,zs, cmap):
    plot = lc([zip(x,y) for (x,y) in zip(xs,ys)], cmap = cmap)
    plot.set_array(array(zs))
    x0,x1 = amin(xs),amax(xs)
    y0,y1 = amin(ys),amax(ys)
    ax.add_collection(plot)
    ax.set_xlim(x0,x1)
    ax.set_ylim(y0,y1)
    return plot
```

`xs` and `ys` are lists of lists of x and y coordinates and `zs` is a list of the different conditions to colorize each line. It feels a bit like a cludge though... I thought that there would be a more neat way to do this. I like the flexibility of the `plt.plot()` function.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

(I know this is an old question but...) Colorbars require a `matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable`, `plt.plot` produces lines which are not scalar mappable, therefore, in order to make a colorbar, we are going to need to make a scalar mappable.

Ok. So the constructor of a `ScalarMappable` takes a `cmap` and a `norm` instance. (norms scale data to the range 0-1, cmaps you have already worked with and take a number between 0-1 and returns a color). So in your case:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=my_cmap, norm=plt.normalize(min=0, max=1))
plt.colorbar(sm)
```

Because your data is in the range 0-1 already, you can simplify the `sm` creation to:

```
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=my_cmap)
```

**EDIT**: For matplotlib v1.2 or greater the code becomes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=my_cmap, norm=plt.normalize(vmin=0, vmax=1))
# fake up the array of the scalar mappable. Urgh...
sm._A = []
plt.colorbar(sm)
```

**EDIT**: For matplotlib v1.3 or greater the code becomes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=my_cmap, norm=plt.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=1))
# fake up the array of the scalar mappable. Urgh...
sm._A = []
plt.colorbar(sm)
```

**EDIT**: For matplotlib v3.1 or greater simplifies to:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=my_cmap, norm=plt.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=1))
plt.colorbar(sm)
```

Answer (score 37):

Here's one way to do it while still using plt.plot(). Basically, you make a throw-away plot and get the colorbar from there.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

min, max = (-40, 30)
step = 10

# Setting up a colormap that's a simple transtion
mymap = mpl.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('mycolors',['blue','red'])

# Using contourf to provide my colorbar info, then clearing the figure
Z = [[0,0],[0,0]]
levels = range(min,max+step,step)
CS3 = plt.contourf(Z, levels, cmap=mymap)
plt.clf()

# Plotting what I actually want
X=[[1,2],[1,2],[1,2],[1,2]]
Y=[[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5]]
Z=[-40,-20,0,30]
for x,y,z in zip(X,Y,Z):
    # setting rgb color based on z normalized to my range
    r = (float(z)-min)/(max-min)
    g = 0
    b = 1-r
    plt.plot(x,y,color=(r,g,b))
plt.colorbar(CS3) # using the colorbar info I got from contourf
plt.show()
```

It's a little wasteful, but convenient. It's also not very wasteful if you make multiple plots as you can call plt.colorbar() without regenerating the info for it.

[image]

Answer (score 21):

Here is a slightly simplied example inspired by the top answer given by [Boris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571475/boris) and [Hooked](https://stackoverflow.com/users/249341/hooked) (Thanks for the great idea!):

### 1. **Discrete colorbar**

Discrete colorbar is more involved, because colormap generated by `mpl.cm.get_cmap()` is not a mappable image needed as a `colorbar()` argument. A dummie mappable needs to generated as shown below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

n_lines = 5
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.sin(x[:, None] + np.pi * np.linspace(0, 1, n_lines))
c = np.arange(1, n_lines + 1)

cmap = mpl.cm.get_cmap('jet', n_lines)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=100)
# Make dummie mappable
dummie_cax = ax.scatter(c, c, c=c, cmap=cmap)
# Clear axis
ax.cla()
for i, yi in enumerate(y.T):
    ax.plot(x, yi, c=cmap(i))
fig.colorbar(dummie_cax, ticks=c)
plt.show();
```

This will produce a plot with a discrete colorbar:
[image]

---

### 2. **Continuous colorbar**

Continuous colorbar is less involved, as `mpl.cm.ScalarMappable()` allows us to obtain an "image" for `colorbar()`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl


n_lines = 5
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.sin(x[:, None] + np.pi * np.linspace(0, 1, n_lines))
c = np.arange(1, n_lines + 1)

norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=c.min(), vmax=c.max())
cmap = mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=mpl.cm.jet)
cmap.set_array([])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=100)
for i, yi in enumerate(y.T):
    ax.plot(x, yi, c=cmap.to_rgba(i + 1))
fig.colorbar(cmap, ticks=c)
plt.show();
```

This will produce a plot with a continuous colorbar:
[image]

**[Side note]** In this example, I personally don't know why `cmap.set_array([])` is necessary (otherwise we'd get error messages). If someone understand the principles under the hood, please comment :)

Comment: It took me a while to realize that your `c=cmap.to_rgba(i + 1)` should be `c=cmap.to_rgba(value)` in the general case, where `value` is value associated with the line that should be mapped to that color.

Answer (score 6):

As other answers here do try to use dummy plots, which is not really good style, here is a generic code for a

### Discrete colorbar

A discrete colorbar is produced in the same way a continuous colorbar is created, just with a different Normalization. In this case a `BoundaryNorm` should be used.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors

n_lines = 5
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.sin(x[:, None] + np.pi * np.linspace(0, 1, n_lines))
c = np.arange(1., n_lines + 1)

cmap = plt.get_cmap("jet", len(c))
norm = matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm(np.arange(len(c)+1)+0.5,len(c))
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap)
sm.set_array([])  # this line may be ommitted for matplotlib >= 3.1

fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=100)
for i, yi in enumerate(y.T):
    ax.plot(x, yi, c=cmap(i))
fig.colorbar(sm, ticks=c)
plt.show()
```

[image]