# Colorbar on Geopandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, geopandas

I am trying to create a Matplotlib colorbar on GeoPandas.

```
import geopandas as gp
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Import csv data
df = df.from_csv('data.csv')

#Convert Pandas DataFrame to GeoPandas DataFrame
g_df = g.GeoDataFrame(df)

#Plot
plt.figure(figsize=(15,15)) 
g_plot = g_df.plot(column='column_name',colormap='hot',alpha=0.08)
plt.colorbar(g_plot)
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-5f33ecf73ac9> in <module>()
      2 plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
      3 g_plot = g_df.plot(column = 'column_name', colormap='hot', alpha=0.08)
----> 4 plt.colorbar(g_plot)

...

AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'autoscale_None'
```

I am not sure how to get colorbar to work.

Comment: GeoDataFrame returns a matplotlib `Axes` object. `plt.colorbar` requires a mappable object (an `Axes` is not a a mappable object).

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**EDIT:** The PR referenced below has been merged into the geopandas master. Now you can simply do:

```
gdf.plot(column='val', cmap='hot', legend=True)
```

and the colorbar will be added automatically.

Notes:

- `legend=True` tells Geopandas to add the colorbar.
- `colormap` is now called `cmap`.
- `vmin` and `vmax` are not required anymore.

See https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mapping.html#creating-a-legend for more (with an example how to adapt the size and placement of the colorbar).

---

There is a PR to add this to geoapandas (https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/pull/172), but for now, you can add it yourself with this workaround:

```
## make up some random data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(20,3), columns=['x', 'y', 'val'])
df['geometry'] = df.apply(lambda row: shapely.geometry.Point(row.x, row.y), axis=1)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df)

## the plotting

vmin, vmax = -1, 1

ax = gdf.plot(column='val', colormap='hot', vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)

# add colorbar
fig = ax.get_figure()
cax = fig.add_axes([0.9, 0.1, 0.03, 0.8])
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap='hot', norm=plt.Normalize(vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax))
# fake up the array of the scalar mappable. Urgh...
sm._A = []
fig.colorbar(sm, cax=cax)
```

The workaround comes from [Matplotlib - add colorbar to a sequence of line plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342549/matplotlib-add-colorbar-to-a-sequence-of-line-plots/11558629#11558629). And the reason that you have to supply `vmin` and `vmax` yourself is because the colorbar is not added based on the data itself, therefore you have to instruct what the link between values and color should be.

Comment: It does get added automatically, but not necessarily in a good way. Can you add a link to the information please how to size, scale, set fonts and otherwise format the legend?

Comment: There is some information in the docs on how to adapt the sizing and placement of the colorbar: https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mapping.html#creating-a-legend