# How do I have uniform color scale for subplots in the form of maps?

Tags: python, pandas, legend, subplot, geopandas

I have plotted the regional distribution of annual coal phase out data in the map of South Korea using geopandas from 2021 to 2030. It looks as following: [image]

One issue is that the color scale for each year or subplot is different because they are based on different columns of a data frame as shown [image].

I want to have a uniform color scale for all years and insert a single legend. How can I have a uniform color scale for each subplot (representing each year) and how do I insert a common legend for all subplots?

Comment: Specify the same `vmin` and `vmax` in reach `plot()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For common colormap, you need to use `vmin` and `vmax` keyword arguments. First, let's compute them.

```
vmin = min(df[year].min() for year in range(2021, 2027))
vmax = max(df[year].max() for year in range(2021, 2027))
```

and modify all plots as follows:

```
south_korea.plot(2021, cmap="Reds", ax=axs[0, 0], vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
```

Now let's add the colorbar for them. I used [Colorbar on Geopandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36008648/colorbar-on-geopandas) to learn how to do it.

```
cax = fig.add_axes([0.9, 0.1, 0.03, 0.8])
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap='Reds', norm=plt.Normalize(vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax))
# fake up the array of the scalar mappable. Urgh...
sm._A = []
fig.colorbar(sm, cax=cax)
```

Note that geopandas uses many functions of matplotlib, so you can transfer the knowledge and search easier.