# matplotlib get colorbar mappable from an axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to add a colorbar WITHOUT what is returned by the axis on plotting things.
Sometimes I draw things to an axis inside a function, which returns nothing. 
Is there a way to get the mappable for a colorbar from an axis where a plotting has been done beforehand? 
I believe there is enough information about colormap and color range bound to the axis itself.

I'd like tp do something like this:

```
def plot_something(ax):
    ax.plot( np.random.random(10), np.random.random(10), c= np.random.random(10))

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2)
plot_something(axs[0])
plot_something(axs[1])

mappable = axs[0].get_mappable() # a hypothetical method I want to have.

fig.colorbar(mappable)
plt.show()
```

**EDIT**

The answer to the possible duplicate can partly solve my problem as is given in the code snippet. However, this question is more about retrieving a general mappable object from an axis, which seems to be impossible according to Diziet Asahi.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matplotlib - add colorbar to a sequence of line plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342549/matplotlib-add-colorbar-to-a-sequence-of-line-plots)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way you could get your mappable would depend on what plotting function your are using in your `plot_something()` function.

for example:

- `plot()` returns a `Line2D` object. A reference to that object is
  stored in the list `ax.lines` of the Axes object. That being said, I don't think a `Line2D` can be used as a mappable for `colorbar()`
- `scatter()` returns a `PathCollection` collection object. This object is stored in the `ax.collections` list of the Axes object.
- On the other hand, `imshow()` returns an `AxesImage` object, which is stored in `ax.images`

You might have to try and look in those different list until you find an appropriate object to use.

```
def plot_something(ax):
    x = np.random.random(size=(10,))
    y = np.random.random(size=(10,))
    c = np.random.random(size=(10,))
    ax.scatter(x,y,c=c)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plot_something(ax)
mappable = ax.collections[0]
fig.colorbar(mappable=mappable)
```

Comment: Hmm... after all, there is no unified way to refer to the mappable object. Then I think this is not a good direction to take. I should try to avoid making plots in this way.