# How to return `ScalarMappable` from `ax` in matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

`Figure.colorbar(mappable=...)` has an argument to accept colorable items, such as `AxesImage`, `ContourSet`, etc. with this in mind, the usual usage is following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable


ax = plt.subplot()
im = ax.imshow(np.arange(100).reshape((10, 10)))

# create an axes on the right side of ax. The width of cax will be 5%
# of ax and the padding between cax and ax will be fixed at 0.05 inch.
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)

plt.colorbar(im, cax=cax)
```

[image]

In above example, the mappable `im` is returned by `imshow()`, which in most cases I think it's nice. My question is **how can we return mappable directly from `ax` after we implemented `ax.imshow()` or `ax.pcolormesh()`**, which should look like something below.

```
ax.imshow(np.arange(100).reshape((10, 10)))
def get_mappable(ax):
    pass

mappable = get_mappable(ax)
```

`ax.images` is not what I want, as this is only one type of mappables.

I looked back into some source code in `plt.colorbar()`, it uses `gci()`([here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/_modules/matplotlib/pyplot.html#colorbar)), but I tried and it returns `None`, I guess I must miss something important. Pls give me some direction, thank you very much.

**Edits**:
I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48141448/5855131), but it is very simialr to `ax.images` method.

Comment: One possible hurdle is that an `ax` can have multiple elements compatible with scalarmappable.  Usually the reason to access that scalarmappable is to create a colorbar. What should the function to when there are multiple such elements? Return them all (it can be a huge list)?  Or maybe try to find out whether or not they would lead to the same colorbar? Or ....?

Comment: Hi, yes, but we can return current mappable . Similar concept in gcf(). It seems in source code, they use gci(), but I tried, it returned None... pls we can use gci(), I think it will be okay. Thanks for your reply.