# Colorbar line plot of multiple lines according to a third variable value

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar, line-plot

**Dataset:** I have a series (n = 30) of X (wavelength) and Y (reflectance) data, each associated with a unique value Z (age). Z values are stored as a separate ordered list.

**Goal:** I am trying to create a series of line plots which display each of the 30 datasets together, where each line is appropriately colored according their Z value (age). I am hoping for weighted colorization depending on the Z value, and an associated colorbar() or similar.

**Attempts**: I tried manipulating *rcParams* to do this by iterating through a color-scheme per plot [i], but the colors are not weighted properly to the Z value. See example figure. I think my issue is similar to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68448380/line-plot-color-depending-on-a-list-value).

I feel like this shouldn't be so hard and that I am missing something obvious!

```
#plot

target_x = nm_names
target_y = data_plot
target_names = ages

N = len(target_y) # number of objects to plot i.e. color cycle count

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [16,7] # fig size
plt.rcParams["axes.prop_cycle"] = plt.cycler("color", plt.cm.PiYG(np.linspace(0,1,N))) # colors to cycle through, choose default like 'viridis' or 'PiYG'

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(N):
    ax.plot(target_x, target_y.iloc[i], label = target_names[i]) # for i in range of objects, plot x,y

#axes
plt.xticks(fontsize = 10, rotation=70, size = 8)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(50))
plt.xlabel('Wavelength (nm)', fontsize = 14)
plt.yticks(fontsize = 12)
plt.ylabel('Normalized Relative Reflectance', fontsize = 13)
plt.title("Spectral Profile", size = 14)
plt.title
plt.xlim(375,2500)

# legend location
box = ax.get_position()
ax.set_position([box.x0, box.y0 + box.height * 0.1,
                 box.width, box.height * .9])

ax.legend(loc='lower left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0),
          fancybox=True, shadow=True, ncol=1, title = 'Age (ky)') # Put a legend below current axis

plt.rcdefaults() # reset global plt parameters, IMPORTANT!
plt.show()
```

[My plot, where 'age' is the 'Z' value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1D0S.png)

Comment: You could create a norm:  `norm = plt.Normalize(vmin=min(ages), vmax=max(ages))` and then use that to color the lines:  `for i in range(N): ax.plot(...., color=plt.cm.PiYG(norm(ages[i])))`.

Comment: @JohanC This seems to work, thank you. Now I will need to figure out how to make 'norm' mappable to a colorbar as "No mappable was found to use for colorbar creation". Labels can be included one at a time using a loop, but a colorbar is needed as I add samples.

Comment: `plt.colorbar(matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=plt.cm.PiYG)` [docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/tutorials/colors/colorbar_only.html)

Comment: Very nice, and I get it now. Thank you.