# how to represent different datasets graphs with gradient color indicating thier value?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

i believe the answer of this question might exist already. but since i cannt express/write the question in the perfect terminology i am having an issue getting an answer.

so my question is, i have lets say 10 devices each one have its own dataframe sets(python,pandas),  and each device has an expiry date as a number. how can i graph some of the datasets from each device as a line with a color which indicate it's expiry data with lets say higher than 1000+ days is red and it gose down to grey at 50 days

i will write a minimal reproducible example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

device_expiry_date = np.array([101, 220, 1000, 43, 592,603,599,499,299,100])

for i in range(10):

                  random_data = np.random.randint(10, 25, size=5)

 
                  df = pd.DataFrame(random_data, columns=['Capacity'])

                  plt.plot(df['Capacity'])
```

so i want each line color to represent how high the expiry date is by somekind of a color gradient or a better option if it exists

Comment: Could you please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @medium-dimensional i did, please check it

Comment: Please see if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342549/matplotlib-add-colorbar-to-a-sequence-of-line-plots